# ultrametric Rademacher theorem

Tags: real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, p-adic-analysis

The classic Rademacher theorem roughly states that Lipschitz continuous functions are almost everywhere differentiable. However, there are well-known ultrametric counterexamples, see Kobliz's classic text for a straightforward exercise describing a Lipschitz continuous and nowhere differentiable function.

What is the best known approximation to the Rademacher theorem for ultrametric spaces?

Comment: I put the [real-analysis] tag on here for the reference to the classic theorem you mention, though it's not appropriate for the general case you are looking for.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks!